# How to prove that $4x \le x^2 + 8$ for all $x$

Tags: proof-writing

I need to find a way to prove the above statement, and feel that doing it by individual cases is not the best method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just write
$$
x^2-4x+8=(x-2)^2+4\geq4>0
$$

Answer (score 1):

$x^2-4x+8$ has no real roots, so if it's positive somewhere, it must be positive everywhere.  (As a consequence of intermediate value theorem.)